# How to format a bash variable to a Docker Compose project name?

Tags: regex, bash, docker, docker-compose

If I have the following file structure:

```
./test/docker-compose.yml
```

and I run `docker-compose up`. The name of the container is formatted like: `test_service_1`.

But if I have this folder:

```
./TeST__-O0%Ri3e/docker-compose.yml
```

and I run `docker-compose up`. The name of the container is formatted like: `test__-o0ri3e_service_1`.

## Question

I store the name of the Docker container I need in a bash variable like this: `${PWD##*/}_service_1`.

*How can I format `${PWD##*/}` so that it reflects the same format Docker Compose uses?*

Comment: Can you show your `docker-compose.yml` in question

Comment: I think project name in compose will help https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name

Comment: Most of the imperative `docker` commands have `docker-compose` equivalents (`docker-compose logs` and `docker-compose exec` are the two you're most likely to need) and you might be able to get away without needing the specific container name.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `-p`

   docker-compose -p a-right-name  up
2. use the file `.env`

   a `.env` in the same folder that `Docker-compose.yml`

content of .env :

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=a-right-name
```

and `docker-compose up` will use ***a-right-name*** as a project_name